# EF Core - Include most recent message in conversation in list query result

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, .net-core

Say there's an entity structure similar to this:

```
class Conversation
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long CreatorId { get; set; }

    public long RecipientId { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    // Populate this with the most recent sent/received message:

    public Message LastMessage { get; set; }
}

class Message
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; } 

    public long SenderId { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Conversation")]
    public long ConversationId { get; set; }

    public Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to populate `LastMessage` with the most recent message for that conversation? The `Message`'s would be mapped to their `Conversation` with the `ConversationId` foreign key.

---

If that's not possible, would it be possible with a conversation entity similar to this?

```
class Conversation
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long CreatorId { get; set; }

    public long RecipientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ConversationId")]
    public IQueryable<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    // Populate these fields with the respective values from the most recent message:

    public long LastMessageSenderId { get; set; }

    public string LastMessageBody { get; set; }
}
```

---

The main thing here is including all of these results in a single `SELECT` query and not having to access `Messages` after the initial results are retrieved since this would all exist within a list of many Conversations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would not have LastMessage on your Conversation Entity, and just query it as needed.  Something like:

```
var q = from c in db.Conversations 
        select new {Conversation=c, LastMessage = c.Messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).Take(1)};
```